# How to properly initialize a boost multi_array of objects?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-array

I have been surprised to find that `boost::multi_array` seems to allocate its initial elements differently from, say, `std::vector`. It does not seem to fill each element with a unique element (using its default value or default constructor). I'm having trouble finding more information about this.

Is there a way to make the `multi_array` fill itself with a unique object at each element?

For example, consider the following:

```
static int num = 0;

struct A {
   int n;
   A() : n((::num)++) {
      std::cout << "A()" << std::endl;
   }
   virtual ~A() {}

   void print() {
      std::cout << "n=" << n << std::endl;
   }
};

int main() {
   std::cout << "vector:" << std::endl;
   std::vector<A> v(3);
   for (auto x : v) {
      x.print();
   }

   std::cout << "multi:" << std::endl;
   boost::multi_array<A, 2> m(boost::extents[2][2]);
   for (auto x : m) {
      for (auto y : x) {
         y.print();
      }
   }
}
```

This results in the output:

```
vector:
A()
A()
A()
n=0
n=1
n=2
multi:
A()
n=3
n=3
n=3
n=3
```

Why is the constructor called only once for the `multi_array`? How can the `multi_array` be "filled out" with unique objects (using `A`'s default constructor)?

Comment: Please note that the behavior of `std::vector` depends on what version of C++ you are using! This is one of those things that changed between C++98 and C++11 standard. (in C++98 the first element is constructed and the rest are copied, in C++11 all are constructed). The behavior of `multi_array` is consistent with old C++98 `std::vector` and was consistent in the past. Maybe an updated (consistent) version of `multi_array` is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quickly fill the whole array do something like `fill_n`¹:

```
std::fill_n(a.data(), a.num_elements(), 0);
```

With boost `multi_array` you can use a view to your own memory buffer to get the same performance (`std::uninitialized_copy` is your friend). (actually, you could even map an array view on existing memory, and you want to keep the existing values).

I've written a comparative demo about this here: [pointers to a class in dynamically allocated boost multi_array, not compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574682/pointers-to-a-class-in-dynamically-allocated-boost-multi-array-not-compiling/27868498#27868498)

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/027a481a702ef2fd)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>

struct octreenode { int a; int b; };

class world {
public:
    world(double x, double y, double z, int widtheast, int widthnorth, int height)
            : 
                originx(x), originy(y), originz(z), 
                chunkseast(widtheast), chunksnorth(widthnorth), chunksup(height)
    {
#define OPTION 4

#if OPTION == 1
        static_assert(std::is_trivially_destructible<octreenode>::value, "assumption made");
        //std::uninitialized_fill_n(chunk.data(), chunk.num_elements(), octreenode {1, 72});
        std::fill_n(chunk.data(), chunk.num_elements(), octreenode {1, 72});
#elif OPTION == 2
        for(auto a:chunk) for(auto b:a) for(auto&c:b) c = octreenode{1, 72};
#elif OPTION == 3
        for (index cz = 0; cz < chunksnorth; ++cz) {
            for (index cx = 0; cx < chunkseast; ++cx) {
                for (index cy = 0; cy < chunksup; ++cy) {
                    chunk[cz][cx][cy] = octreenode{1, 72};
                }
            }
        }
#elif OPTION == 4
        static_assert(std::is_trivially_destructible<octreenode>::value, "assumption made");
        for (index cz = 0; cz < chunksnorth; ++cz) {
            for (index cx = 0; cx < chunkseast; ++cx) {
                for (index cy = 0; cy < chunksup; ++cy) {
                    new (&chunk[cz][cx][cy]) octreenode{1, 72};
                }
            }
        }
#endif
        (void) originx, (void) originy, (void) originz, (void) chunksup, (void) chunkseast, (void) chunksnorth;
    }

private:
    double originx, originy, originz;
    int chunkseast, chunksnorth, chunksup;

#if 1
    typedef boost::multi_array<octreenode, 3> planetchunkarray; // a boost_multi for chunks
    typedef planetchunkarray::index index;
    planetchunkarray chunk{boost::extents[chunksnorth][chunkseast][chunksup]};
#else
    static_assert(boost::is_trivially_destructible<octreenode>::value, "assumption made");

    std::unique_ptr<octreenode[]> raw { new octreenode[chunksnorth*chunkseast*chunksup] };
    typedef boost::multi_array_ref<octreenode, 3> planetchunkarray;
    typedef planetchunkarray::index index;
    planetchunkarray chunk{raw.get(), boost::extents[chunksnorth][chunkseast][chunksup]};
#endif
};

int main() {
    world w(1,2,3,4,5,6);
}
```

The variant using `multi_array_ref` is an example of how to avoid copy-constructing the elements (it's akin to the optimization used by `std::vector` when it uses uninitialized memory for reserved but unused elements).

---

¹ Of course for unique values, use `std::iota` or `std::generate`

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n

Comment: I think this may be true for `std::array` (certainly for plain C/C++ arrays). But `boost::multi_array` does seem to initialize its elements. It just does so differently than `std::vector`, as I found out after posting this question.

Comment: @Corey I've expanded my answer with some more information including a demo that shows how you might use `multi_array_ref` to get in-place element construction going. Remember: premature optimization is at the root of all evil :)

Comment: Thanks for the example of how to use pre-allocated memory; that may be useful. It actually wasn't my goal in this case -- I was mostly just confused why I wasn't seeing the default constructor being called and thought I was doing something wrong. ...I'm considering accepting my own answer because it demonstrates what's going on in the opening question, which could be useful for someone finding this question in the future.

Answer (score 1):

So on further study, I learned two things:

1. `boost::multi_array` uses the copy constructor to initialize objects into the container, not the default constructor.
2. The `for (auto x : container)` way of looping in C++11 seems (at least with clang++ 3.5) to loop over *copies* of the container elements, rather than iterators (or references).

**Modifying the original question's example to demonstrate point 1.**

Adding a copy constructor (and corresponding counter), and using `auto& x` for the object loops rather than `auto x`:

```
 static int num = 0;
 static int cpy = 0;
 struct A {
    int n;
    int c;
    A() : n((::num)++), c(0) {
       std::cout << "A_def()" << std::endl;
    }
    A(const A& o) : n(0), c((::cpy)++) {
       std::cout << "A_cpy()" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual ~A() {}

    void print() {
       std::cout << "n=" << n << ",c=" << c << std::endl;
    }
 };

 int main() {
    std::cout << "vector:" << std::endl;
    std::vector<A> v(3);
    for (auto& x : v) {
       x.print();
    }

    std::cout << "multi:" << std::endl;
    boost::multi_array<A, 2> m(boost::extents[2][2]);

    for (auto x : m) {
       for (auto& y : x) {
          y.print();
       }
    }
 }
```

Produces the output

```
 vector:
 A_def()  // <- vector allocation starts
 A_def()
 A_def()
 n=0,c=0  // <- vector printing starts, using "for (auto& x)"
 n=1,c=0
 n=2,c=0
 multi:
 A_def()  // <- a temporary object for multi_array allocation
 A_cpy()  // <- multi_array allocation starts
 A_cpy()
 A_cpy()
 A_cpy()
 n=0,c=0  // <- multi_array prints starts, using "for (auto& y)"
 n=0,c=1
 n=0,c=2
 n=0,c=3
```

**Modifying the example above to demonstrate point 2.**

Same class definition as above in this answer, but removing the `auto& x` from the object loops, and going back to using `auto x` as done in the original question.

```
    std::cout << "vector:" << std::endl;
    std::vector<A> v(3);
    for (auto x : v) {
       x.print();
    }

    std::cout << "multi:" << std::endl;
    boost::multi_array<A, 2> m(boost::extents[2][2]);

    for (auto x : m) {
       for (auto y : x) {
          y.print();
       }
    }
```

Produces output that shows the copy constructor gets called during the `print` loops, even for elements in the `vector`.

```
 vector:
 A_def()  // <- vector allocation starts
 A_def()
 A_def()
 A_cpy()  // <- vector printing starts, using "for (auto x)"
 n=0,c=0
 A_cpy()
 n=0,c=1
 A_cpy()
 n=0,c=2
 multi:
 A_def()  // <- a temporary object for multi_array allocation
 A_cpy()  // <- multi_array allocation starts
 A_cpy()
 A_cpy()
 A_cpy()
 A_cpy()  // <- multi_array printing starts, using "for (auto y)"
 n=0,c=7
 A_cpy()
 n=0,c=8
 A_cpy()
 n=0,c=9
 A_cpy()
 n=0,c=10
```

Comment: Derp. Of course `for (auto x : c)` loops over copies. Perhaps you could try `for (auto& x: c)` to  loop over lvalues (Edit: ah you noticed. Then I'm not sure why you still point it out as if it was something interesting about multi array)

Comment: @sehe I didn't mean to point it out as something special to `multi_array`, it was just one of the changes that needed to be made to the original question. Regarding `multi_array`, the important bit is that it uses the copy constructor, not the default one like `vector` does.